# Shuffle items in a predictable sequence

Tags: php, sorting, random, sequence

I have 10 000 of IDs, that are initially sorted in a standard ascending way. 
I need to shuffle these IDs in a specific way, so that resulting sequence could be replicated later.

Obviously if I use rand() or mt_rand(), sequence is different every time, so I need some kind of method, that would shuffle items with predictable results.

Here is what I tried before:

```
public function pseudoRandomSort(&$ids, $var1)
{
    $sorted = array();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $sorted[md5($id.$var1)] = $id;            
    }
    ksort($sorted);
    $ids = array_values($sorted);
}
```

This method works, but I am looking for something more elegant and faster

---

UPD: Thanks to @Andrew for mentioning the $seed concept. 
Basing on it I made a simple and fast method that shuffles items in a predictable sequence:

```
public function predictableShuffle(&$ids, $seed)
{
    srand($seed);
    shuffle($ids);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting these id's from a database? I mean are they id's from a tables rows?

Comment: No, they are stored in a file

Comment: What have you already done ?

Comment: So, you want to sort? Not want to sort? Want to randomize? The function name `pseudoRandomSort` is dubious at best.

Comment: @AlexKapustin, I did this:
`public function pseudoRandomSort(&$ids, $var1)
    {
        $sorted = array();
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $sorted[md5($id.$var1)] = $id;
        }
        ksort($sorted);
        $ids = array_values($sorted);
    }`
It takes about 0.02 s on a shared hosting to randomize 10 000 ids 
I wanted to find out if there is a faster an may be more elegant way

Comment: @Mast
_You want to sort?_ YES ----------
_Not want to sort?_ Obviously want to sort ----------
_Want to randomize?_ YES, I want to sort randomly. Isn't this correct to say it in English? Can't we sort in a random way? Or in random-like way? ----------

Take look at example `pseudoRandomSort`, that was provided as answer to @AlexKapustin

Comment: A shuffle is not a sort, but now I understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or at least a variation of it.

You have to shuffle them based on a seed. Since it's a lot easier to store a seed rather than store the whole sequence of X numbers.

The simplest implementation would look like this:

```
$items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function shuffleSeed(&$items, $seed) {
  $items = array_values($items);
  mt_srand($seed);
  $count = count($items);
  for ($i = $count - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $j = mt_rand(0, $i);
    list($items[$i], $items[$j]) = [$items[$j], $items[$i]];
  }
}

shuffleSeed($items, 3);

var_dump($items);
```

Since you said the performance is quite important here this may not be good to use, you'll have to mix and match. Give it a go and see how it performs.

Comment: Thanks!
It takes about 0.01s on a shared hosting to randomize 10 000 items using this approach. This timing is acceptable. It looks more elegant and it is about 2 times faster than temporary workaround that I had before. 
I just slightly minimized the code:
`mt_srand($seed);
        foreach (array_keys($items) as $i) {
            $j = mt_rand(0, $i);
            list($items[$i], $items[$j]) = array($items[$j], $items[$i]);
        }`